# React: Am I using conditional rendering wrongly as it seems to not evaluate as expected?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, conditional-statements, react-hooks, session-storage

I have a little application where I want to render components differently for logged in user/admin accounts.

E.g. for normal users I'd like to have header menus "User1" and "User2", for admin users "Admin1", "Admin2", ...

At the login screen, input information is stored in session storage in a class "AuthHelper".
Admin users are required to have "admin" in name, otherwise it's handled as a normal user (for testing purposes)

```
export default class AuthHelper {


    login = (username, password, cb) => {

        window.sessionStorage.setItem("username", username)
        window.sessionStorage.setItem("password", password)
        let isAdmin = username.includes("admin") ? true:false

        window.sessionStorage.setItem('adminState', isAdmin)

        setTimeout(() => {
            cb()
        }, 100);
    }

    logout = (cb) => {
            window.sessionStorage.clear()
            setTimeout(() => {
                cb()
            }, 100);

    }

    isLoggedIn = () => {
        if (window.sessionStorage.getItem('username') == null) {
            return false
        }
        return true
    }

    isAdmin = () => {
        return window.sessionStorage.getItem('adminState')
    }
}
```

In App.js, I firstly want to render my header menu only for logged in admin users:

```
function App() {
  const auth = new AuthHelper()
  const [isLoggedIn, setIsLoggedIn] = useState(false)

 useEffect(() => {

 })

  return (
    <div>
      <BrowserRouter>
        <header>
          <div className="header-title">
            <h1>Service</h1>
          </div>
          <div className="header-links">
          {
              //window.sessionStorage.getItem('adminState') && 
              auth.isAdmin() &&
              (
              <ul className="menu-list">
                <Link to="/overview">Admin1</Link>
                <Link to="/order">Admin2</Link>
                <Logout setIsLoggedIn={setIsLoggedIn} />
              </ul>
             )
          }
          </div>
          ...
```

However, even though the `auth.isAdmin()` correctly returns false when logging in console (as normal user logs in), the menu
always is displayed. What am I missing here? How would I go on with this to display different header menus according to the user login status?

Furthermore, are the callback function in the methods of "Auth" required with the delay of 100 milliseconds or are they pointless actually? Passed "cb" function invokes passed setter hook of App.js "setIsLoggedIn" to achieve rerendering of App.js as a whole to display the menu. Is passing the hook setter into  and  to invoke them to trigger rerendering of  legitimate or a bad idea?

Glad for any suggestions and feedback!

Answer (score 1):

Most probably in session storage all values saved as strings: string 'true' or string 'false', and string is always return true when you convert it to boolean type, so just change your condition

```
isAdmin = () => {
  return window.sessionStorage.getItem('adminState') === 'true'
}
```

and it should work